# Loop Over Set of Files?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I am trying to process a list of files to a function (similar to a "for f in file1 file2 file3 file5   do ... in Bash"):

```
import System.Directory

returnDirectoryContents :: IO [FilePath]
returnDirectoryContents = do
  let path = "."
  filter (isSuffixOf ".txt") <$> getDirectoryContents path

countNumberOfWords :: FilePath -> IO Int
countNumberOfWords path = do ...
```

`countNumberOfWords "file1.txt"` works fine.
However, I cannot map the function to a list of FilePath:

```
fmap countNumberOfWords returnDirectoryContents
    • No instance for (Show (IO Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
```

What is the correct way to process a list of files to a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `map`'s monadic brother, `mapM`.

Comment: You can also use [`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) and [`traverse_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_) instead of `mapM` and `mapM_` with a more general `Applicative` constraint rather than `Monad`.

Answer (score 2):

The broad answer to the question "How to loop over a list" is "Be more specific". Imperative languages have this funny concept called a "loop", that encompasses several different patterns of repeating. You can accumulate a new list, you can sum data, you can perform side effects, all of these different operations encompassed into, more or less, one massively powerful `for` loop construct.

However, Haskell isn't like that. In Haskell, when you think "I want to loop over X", you need to think about what you actually want to do to your data.

If you want to do something to each element of a list and produce a new list of the results, that's [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map).

```
map (\x -> x + 1) myList
```

If you want to take a sublist of the list, based on some condition, that's [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter).

```
filter (\x -> x > 0) myList
```

If you want to accumulate the values of the list into a single value using an operation like `(+)` or `(*)`, that's a fold operation such as [`foldl'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-) or [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldr) (see [this Haskell wiki page for more details on the difference](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)).

```
foldr (+) 0 myList
```

There are also some more specific functions for common operations, like `sum` which is basically `foldr (+) 0` or `maximum` which is basically `foldr1 max`.

Finally, each of the operations above has a monadic variable that ends in a capital M. `map` has [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM), `filter` has [`filterM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:filterM), and `foldl` has [`foldM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM). Each of these is identical to its pure variant except that it carries a monadic state to its result. For instance, we can compare the types

```
map  ::            (a ->   b) -> ([a] ->   [b])
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> ([a] -> m [b])

filter  ::            (a ->   Bool) -> [a] ->   [a]
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]

foldl ::            (a -> b ->   a) -> a -> [b] ->   a
foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
```

In each case, we simply add an `m` to the result of any function (either input or output).

Now in your case, the action you want to perform is `FilePath -> IO Int`, which is an IO action (hence, a monadic action). And it sounds like you want to do it to each list element. So that's `mapM`.

```
mapM countNumberOfWords myList
```

If the input to your operation is the result of another monadic action like `returnDirectoryContents`, you can pipe it into the `mapM` call with the bind `(>>=)` operator.

```
returnDirectoryContents >>= mapM countNumberOfWords
```

Finally, the type of this expression is `IO [Int]`. If you don't care about the `[Int]` and just want to execute this for its IO action, you can use the variant called [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) to ignore the result value.

```
returnDirectoryContents >>= mapM_ countNumberOfWords
```

This has type `IO ()`, which is an appropriate return value from `main` for example.

But the broad lesson here is that, when manipulating data in Haskell (whether lists or some other kind of data), we generally work using higher-level operations rather than just falling back to one catch-all control construct like a loop. Technically, the direct equivalent of looping in Haskell is recursion, and we could've reimplemented `mapM_` using direct recursion, but the resulting function would have been far less readable.

An experienced Haskeller is familiar with the operations defined for their favorite types and uses those to perform high-level operations. And if you continue in Haskell, you'll start to learn these same functions as well.